# Handling Images - WCF

Tags: vb.net, wcf, image

Here so much about this site so I'll try my luck if you could help me enlighten in my problem.

What would be the best options to handle images in .Net 3.5 framework and SQL Server for a WINAPP that is incorporated with WCF? I need use this images for transactions inside the system.

Comment: "Use images for transactions"????? Do you mean that you want to use images to represent certain info on the screen?

Comment: very unclear - what is it you want to do?? Upload images to a WCF service and store them in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to send images over WCF is to use streaming. (Google for WCF Streaming).

For storing images in SQL Server there are several options, data type varbinary(max) has worked well for us.

Answer (score 0):

what i meant is there are process in th system that requires an image data. For now, I store the image in the database by converting it to a base64string and saving it. When wcf is implemented the retrieval of data with images is slow.

Comment: @hunny: welcome to SO. Please read the FAQ (the link http://stackoverflow.com/faq) is at the bottom of every page. You'll find that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site. You should edit your question with this information, and not add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just mentioned the below text in another answer, but it's relevant to you as well, so I'll copy paste what I wrote there.

Have you considered using WCF's raw programming model? [This blog post details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx) how to use the programming model on the service side, and [this follow-up blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-web.aspx) details how to use it on the client side. I've seen it used quite a bit for file upload and image transfer scenarios, so it might help your situation as well!